# S3 api policy condition to restrict file type / extension

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I'm reading [the doc here](http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html#Access_Control) but I can't see how to add a condition to restrict uploads to some whitelist of extension / mime types.

ie: I'd like to only allow people to upload files with extensions "xls", "xlsx", "ppt", "pptx", "doc", "docx", "txt", "csv"

Is this possible?

PS: I'm using `jquery-file-upload` and already check client side before my `POST` to s3 but some browsers don't support the File api so I need a double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely to validate by its mime type

(which might be useless, since if a mimetype isn't registered, it will pick the default one for a binary unknown type, from the browser perspective).

In the docs, its referred as such:

```
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
```

I'm not sure if sets are allowed. At the very least, you could combine several policies, one for each allowed mime type.

As for Extension, I guess you have no options, though.

Edit: I've wrote a post a while ago [outlining how the whole process works](http://www.newvem.com/beyond-get-and-put-sharing-s3-objects-effectively-via-http-with-some-sdk-help/) and how to use it (Disclaimer: I write for Newvem)

Comment: As I already wrote, I consider it's a partial answer. I'll accept it later if nothing better arrives

Comment: I accept this answer, this nothing better showed up, thanks :)

Comment: Did you find a way for restricting access at bucket level?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        maxFileSize: 25000000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        process: [
            {
                action: 'load',
                fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
                maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
            },
            {
                action: 'save'
            }
        ]
    });
```

The fileTypes option seems to be what you're looking for. Change the regular expression to filter what types you want. My example shows those for image files.